# How to speed up my logistic regression bootstrapped R function?

Tags: r, performance, loops, classification, regression

I am bootstrapping a logistic regression by looping over a function many times and storing my results.

Can I make this run faster? I had a loop within the function which is now gone but still not fats enough. Any suggestions?

```
# Bootstraping a logistic regression
# First create a function which takes a random sample from our data = 1000 and predicts
# have it return the prediction for the validation set using this sampled model

    boot_fun <- function(){

      train_data <- bankdata[train_set,]
      rows_sample <- sample(1:nrow(train_data), 1000, TRUE)
      LR_model <- glm(y~., data = train_data[rows_sample,], family = 'binomial')
      pred <- predict(LR_model, type = 'response', newdata = bankdata[valid_set,])

      pred <- cbind(pred, rep(0,length(pred)))
      pred[which(pred[,1] > 0.5),] <- 1

      return(pred[,2])
    }



# We new run this function as many times as we want to bootstrap
# First create an output dataframe
# A loop error handling function tryCatch had to be used. Some samples didn't include December for 
# example and was generating an error when trying to predict using a model with an unexistent December


    boot_distribution <- data.frame(rep(NA,length(valid_set)))

    n <- 10000

    for (i in 1:n) {

      tryCatch({
        cat('processing.....at.....', round(i/n, digits = 3)*100,' % ', '\n')
        boot_distribution <- cbind(boot_distribution, boot_fun())

      }, error = function(e){cat('One of the regressions was unsucessful..', conditionMessage(e), '\n')})

    }
```

Comment: Either you have a faster way to train the `glm` or you parallelize the loop.

Comment: growing the columns of your results in the for loop is likely to be slow. you can collapse the whole latter bit to `boot_distribution <- replicate(n, boot_fun())`. To keep the error checking move `tryCatch` into your `boot_fun()`. Then if still too slow (likely when running 10,000! bootstraps -- are you sure this isnt overkill) you can run in parallel.